# ListView-deleting item form listView: android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android, I'm using a ListView in my code. My code is as following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
int counter;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
Button btnAddAgain, btnDeleteSelected;
ArrayList <String>listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter=0;
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,listItems);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAddAgain=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addAgain);
    btnAddAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            listItems.add("Clicked " +counter++);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    btnDeleteSelected=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnDeleteSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Delete?");
            builder.setTitle("Confirm Action");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (checked.get(i)==true)
                        {
                            listItems.remove(i);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    //checked.clear();
                }
             });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
    });




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

But delete button removing only first element of the ListView. Someone please help me. I'm trying to learn android myself. Your help will be very beneficial for me to learn android. What change I do in the code to delete checked item from the list. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int size = listItems.size() - 1;
                for (int i = size; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    if (checked.get(i))
                    {
                        listItems.remove(i);

                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //checked.clear();
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, getCheckedItemPositions() returns false for all values when you use .get().
What you want to use instead is checked.valueAt(i)==true
Look at here on [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html)

The way that the SparseBooleanArray is populated in your case seems to be without a key, which means that all of your .get(key) will return false because it cannot find the item. Instead, you should just use valueAt(int index) since you can use an index to find which items are true.

Therefore, your code should be the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (checked.valueAt(i)==true)
                        {
                            listItems.remove(i);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`listView.getCheckedItemPositions();` return only checked positions

Try this code

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
int min = 0;
for(int i=0; i<checked.size();i++){
    int pos = checked.keyAt(i);
    listItems.remove(pos - min);
    min++;
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helped you;